# Is there a way to define sets, variables and constraints intelligently in PYOMO without cross product?

Tags: python, pyomo

### I have three different sets

1. Number of Store - 100
2. Number of Products - 10
3. Number of Size in each product - 10

I want to create Parameter in pyomo which is combination of above three sets. Basically i want to skip cross product which have code snippet below.

Reason to skip below approach is each product can have 10 different sizes and no need to create combination of product of A and sizes coming from product B, which doesn't make sense.

Code snippet with cross product:

```
model            = pyo.AbstractModel()
model.stores     = pyo.Set()
model.sizes      = pyo.Set()
model.packs      = pyo.Set()
model.products   = pyo.Set()
model.demand     = pyo.Param(model.clusters,
                             model.products,
                             model.sizes, default = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand your dilemma, the sizes are different for different products and a universal cross-set of products and sizes doesn't work because of that.

I think you have 2 options.  Either works.

The easies thing to do would be just to make tuples of product-size pairs and use that as a set...basically merging the products with their sizes.

products = {(shoes, 12), (shoes, 13), (shoes, 5), (pants, XL), (pants, L),...}

It is perfectly legitimate to use a flat set like that and use that to initialize your `pyomo.Set`.  It might get a little tricky if you need to sum over individual products because that info is merged with the sizes.  Not sure if that is needed.

Option 2 is to use an indexed set, so you would have sets of sizes that are indexed by product.  [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73996930/using-discontinuous-indices-for-pyomo-optimization/73997720#73997720) using EV's and times.  You would set it up similarly for products & sizes.

Comment: Exactly i was trying to implement first suggestion, but i have few constraints which need to sum up and there getting error as no valid combinations available in data.

Comment: I got the second solution and it will help on skipping unrelated constraints. Is there any other alternative solution in PYOMO like GAMS where it internally takes care of building Sets, Variables and Constraints?

Comment: On the first comment, you are going to need to post a reproducible example for someone to see what is going wrong.  On the second comment, I don't understand what you are asking.  I'm not a GAMS user.