# Pyomo dealing with an indexed index

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

Some context to my optimization: I have a warehouse that has stocked products that can be allocated
to several retail stores. Each retail store has a monthly demand that needs to be satisifed but I would like to charge each store the highest possible price. So I have a set of stores and a set of products, but these products can only be used in certain months.

Below is the mathematical formulation:

[image]

Where

[image]

So x_{i,j} represents the allocation to store n of product i. r_n is just a known risk factor for each store, pi_n is the current profit per store, p_n is the current price and paid by store n and demand_n is the demand for store n. These are all known.

**So for simplicity's sake, we could simply maximise avgPrice, the rest of the variables I can handle.**

So the average price paid by a store is the average of the monthly prices they pay for their demanded products. I assume a store will only have demands during a year, hence the division by 12. So for each month I allocate products to n stores, find the total price paid by each store, and then find the average of these values.

The issue I am having is how to deal with the

[image]

part. So P_{t} is the available products I have in month t. This is stored in a dictionary of pandas dataframes that look something like:

| Product ID | Product Amount | Price per unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 | 2 |
| 456 | 20 | 6 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 999 | 30 | 7 |

And I have one of these for each month (so my dictionary can be indexed like `df_dict[jan], df_dict[feb]` etc.

For example, store n = 1 could have a demand of 30 units in January, so I could allocate product 123 and 456 to them, and get a total price in January of 10 * 2+20 * 6  (c_{i} in the formulation above is the unit price).

Some code for reproducibility:

```
demand_dict = {('store_1', 'jan'): 237.2,
 ('store_1', 'feb'): 239,
 ('store_1', 'mar'): 216,
 ('store_1', 'apr'): 119,
 ('store_2', 'may'): 624}
# this constains over 50 stores, each of which have 12 monthly demands
```

This is used to ensure demand constraints. So I create a set of stores by:

```
store_set = demand_dict.keys()
```

And I have a set of months:

```
mon_set = ['jan', 'feb',...'dec']
```

The product dictionary looks something like:

```
prod_dict['jan'] = {'Product Amount': {123: 50,
  456: 31,
  789: 50,
  101: 31,
  102: 70,
  103: 33,
  104: 30,
  105: 14},
'Unit price': {123: 9,
  456: 9,
  789: 7.6,
  101: 7.2,
  102: 6.4,
  103: 5.5,
  104: 5.2,
  105: 5.1}

prod_dict['feb'] = {'Product Amount': {200: 50,
  201: 31,
  202: 50,
  203: 31,
  204: 70,
  205: 33,
  206: 30,
  207: 14},
'Unit price': {200: 9,
  201: 9,
  202: 7,
  203: 7,
  204: 6,
  205: 5,
  206: 5,
  207: 5}
```

Given this formulation of the product set, I don't understand how I can create this as a pyomo set. I am confused because each product (indexed by its id) can be allocated to each store. So if I have 5 stores, product id 123 can be allocated to each of them, as long as I do not allocate more than what is available in the product amount. This constraint I think I can handle. I am however completely lost when it comes to creating the product set in pyomo because the set itself is indexed by a month.

Lastly, I know this does not look like an optimization problem because I could simply allocate the most expensive products to each store. However, the risk factor, r_n, contains variables that make this an actual QP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piece that I think you are missing is an indexed set that indexes which products are available/priced for particular months.  That is essentially the `P_t` piece that you want.  So you can create a "set of sets" in `pyomo` where the inner set is indexed by another set, in this case, you have sets of products that are indexed by another component, months.  These can be highly useful, but also tricky to use, and I think it is almost always required to "flatten" this set out after you make it so that you can use it in other contexts.  Below is an example.  I also showed this concept [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73996930/using-discontinuous-indices-for-pyomo-optimization/73997720#73997720).

##### Code:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

# DATA
prod_dict = {}
prod_dict['jan'] = {'Product Amount': {123: 50,
  456: 31,
  789: 50,
  101: 31,
  102: 70,
  103: 33,
  104: 30,
  105: 14},
'Unit price': {123: 9,
  456: 9,
  789: 7.6,
  101: 7.2,
  102: 6.4,
  103: 5.5,
  104: 5.2,
  105: 5.1}}

prod_dict['feb'] = {'Product Amount': {200: 50,
  201: 31,
  202: 50,
  203: 31,
  204: 70,
  205: 33,
  206: 30,
  207: 14},
'Unit price': {200: 9,
  201: 9,
  202: 7,
  203: 7,
  204: 6,
  205: 5,
  206: 5,
  207: 5}}

# helper function
def products_by_month(month):
  products = set(prod_dict[month]['Product Amount'])
  # sanity check:
  assert set(prod_dict[month]['Unit price']) == products
  return products

# make set of all products, if not already available...
products = set.union(*[products_by_month(m) for m in prod_dict.keys()])

# Model Parts
model = pyo.ConcreteModel('sales')

# SETS
model.M =  pyo.Set(initialize=list(prod_dict.keys()))  # Set of Months
# aside:  making a list of the set keeps pyomo 
#         from complaining about unordered collection...
model.P =  pyo.Set(initialize=list(products))    # Set of all Products
model.MP = pyo.Set(model.M, within=model.P, initialize={m: list(products_by_month(m)) for m in model.M})

# a flattened set for convenience...
model.MP_flat = pyo.Set(within=model.M * model.P, initialize={(m, p) for m in model.M for p in model.MP[m]})

# PARAMS
model.price     = pyo.Param(model.MP_flat, initialize={(m, p): prod_dict[m]['Unit price'][p] for m, p in model.MP_flat})
model.inventory = pyo.Param(model.MP_flat, initialize={(m, p): prod_dict[m]['Product Amount'][p] for m, p in model.MP_flat})

# VARS
model.deliver = pyo.Var(model.MP_flat, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

# CONSTRAINTS
# example to limit sale of product by month to available in that month
@model.Constraint(model.MP_flat)
def delivery_limit(model, month, product):
  return model.deliver[month, product] <= model.inventory[month, product]

# example to limit all sales of product in a month to arbitrary cost (this uses the indexed set that you will need)
@model.Constraint(model.M)
def cost_limit(model, month):
  return sum(model.deliver[month, product] * model.price[month, product] for product in model.MP[month]) <= 100

model.pprint()
```

##### Output (a little long, based on your example data):

```
5 Set Declarations
    M : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    2 : {'jan', 'feb'}
    MP : Size=2, Index=M, Ordered=Insertion
        Key : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        feb :     1 :      P :    8 : {200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207}
        jan :     1 :      P :    8 : {101, 102, 103, 456, 104, 105, 789, 123}
    MP_flat : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain         : Size : Members
        None :     2 : MP_flat_domain :   16 : {('jan', 456), ('feb', 204), ('feb', 200), ('jan', 105), ('jan', 102), ('feb', 202), ('feb', 203), ('feb', 206), ('jan', 101), ('jan', 789), ('jan', 104), ('feb', 205), ('jan', 123), ('jan', 103), ('feb', 201), ('feb', 207)}
    MP_flat_domain : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    M*P :   32 : {('jan', 101), ('jan', 102), ('jan', 103), ('jan', 456), ('jan', 104), ('jan', 105), ('jan', 200), ('jan', 201), ('jan', 202), ('jan', 203), ('jan', 204), ('jan', 205), ('jan', 206), ('jan', 207), ('jan', 789), ('jan', 123), ('feb', 101), ('feb', 102), ('feb', 103), ('feb', 456), ('feb', 104), ('feb', 105), ('feb', 200), ('feb', 201), ('feb', 202), ('feb', 203), ('feb', 204), ('feb', 205), ('feb', 206), ('feb', 207), ('feb', 789), ('feb', 123)}
    P : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :   16 : {101, 102, 103, 456, 104, 105, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 789, 123}

2 Param Declarations
    inventory : Size=16, Index=MP_flat, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key          : Value
        ('feb', 200) :    50
        ('feb', 201) :    31
        ('feb', 202) :    50
        ('feb', 203) :    31
        ('feb', 204) :    70
        ('feb', 205) :    33
        ('feb', 206) :    30
        ('feb', 207) :    14
        ('jan', 101) :    31
        ('jan', 102) :    70
        ('jan', 103) :    33
        ('jan', 104) :    30
        ('jan', 105) :    14
        ('jan', 123) :    50
        ('jan', 456) :    31
        ('jan', 789) :    50
    price : Size=16, Index=MP_flat, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key          : Value
        ('feb', 200) :     9
        ('feb', 201) :     9
        ('feb', 202) :     7
        ('feb', 203) :     7
        ('feb', 204) :     6
        ('feb', 205) :     5
        ('feb', 206) :     5
        ('feb', 207) :     5
        ('jan', 101) :   7.2
        ('jan', 102) :   6.4
        ('jan', 103) :   5.5
        ('jan', 104) :   5.2
        ('jan', 105) :   5.1
        ('jan', 123) :     9
        ('jan', 456) :     9
        ('jan', 789) :   7.6

1 Var Declarations
    deliver : Size=16, Index=MP_flat
        Key          : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        ('feb', 200) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('feb', 201) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('feb', 202) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('feb', 203) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('feb', 204) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('feb', 205) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('feb', 206) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('feb', 207) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('jan', 101) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('jan', 102) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('jan', 103) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('jan', 104) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('jan', 105) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('jan', 123) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('jan', 456) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        ('jan', 789) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals

2 Constraint Declarations
    cost_limit : Size=2, Index=M, Active=True
        Key : Lower : Body                                                                                                                                                                              : Upper : Active
        feb :  -Inf :             9*deliver[feb,200] + 9*deliver[feb,201] + 7*deliver[feb,202] + 7*deliver[feb,203] + 6*deliver[feb,204] + 5*deliver[feb,205] + 5*deliver[feb,206] + 5*deliver[feb,207] : 100.0 :   True
        jan :  -Inf : 7.2*deliver[jan,101] + 6.4*deliver[jan,102] + 5.5*deliver[jan,103] + 9*deliver[jan,456] + 5.2*deliver[jan,104] + 5.1*deliver[jan,105] + 7.6*deliver[jan,789] + 9*deliver[jan,123] : 100.0 :   True
    delivery_limit : Size=16, Index=MP_flat, Active=True
        Key          : Lower : Body             : Upper : Active
        ('feb', 200) :  -Inf : deliver[feb,200] :  50.0 :   True
        ('feb', 201) :  -Inf : deliver[feb,201] :  31.0 :   True
        ('feb', 202) :  -Inf : deliver[feb,202] :  50.0 :   True
        ('feb', 203) :  -Inf : deliver[feb,203] :  31.0 :   True
        ('feb', 204) :  -Inf : deliver[feb,204] :  70.0 :   True
        ('feb', 205) :  -Inf : deliver[feb,205] :  33.0 :   True
        ('feb', 206) :  -Inf : deliver[feb,206] :  30.0 :   True
        ('feb', 207) :  -Inf : deliver[feb,207] :  14.0 :   True
        ('jan', 101) :  -Inf : deliver[jan,101] :  31.0 :   True
        ('jan', 102) :  -Inf : deliver[jan,102] :  70.0 :   True
        ('jan', 103) :  -Inf : deliver[jan,103] :  33.0 :   True
        ('jan', 104) :  -Inf : deliver[jan,104] :  30.0 :   True
        ('jan', 105) :  -Inf : deliver[jan,105] :  14.0 :   True
        ('jan', 123) :  -Inf : deliver[jan,123] :  50.0 :   True
        ('jan', 456) :  -Inf : deliver[jan,456] :  31.0 :   True
        ('jan', 789) :  -Inf : deliver[jan,789] :  50.0 :   True

10 Declarations: M P MP MP_flat_domain MP_flat price inventory deliver delivery_limit cost_limit
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much! I just have two small questions: 1. I don't quite understand the use of the constraint decorators such as @model.Constraint(model.MP_flat) vs. @model.Constraint(model.M)
2.  The model.deliver variable appears to be indexed by (month, product_id), but could I not create a set of all stores and then index it by (store_index, product_id) such that I can see how much I am allocating to each store? Or am I confusing myself and need both constraints?

Comment: 1.  The decorator syntax is a new feature, and it is equivalent to using the function & rule combo.  (see some of my other `pyomo` answers).  The argument in the decorator is the domain (? right word) of the constraint...  the "for each" part.  In the first constraint, we are limiting the delivery **for each** product-month pair.  The second constraint is a limit **for each** month, but uses the products within that month's within `MP[month]`.  <-- this is the basis of the question you asked about getting a set of products indexed by month.

Comment: 2.  Yeah, I left out the stores just to keep the example concise.  You almost certainly are going to modify to be `model.deliver[month, product, store]` for a decision variable, so just create it by adding store in the definition, along with `MP_flat` to get the full x-product.  I recommend you chop your data down to just 2 months and maybe 4 or 5 products while you devlope this and *keep printing the model* to QA what is being generated!

Comment: Ah of course, thanks a lot for clarifying!