# How can I index a variable in Pyomo with two lists or Sets, but have the second list be different for each element of the first list?

Tags: python, pyomo

I am learning Pyomo and I want to try to build a variable that is indexed by two lists or set. This is easy if for each element of the list N the elements of the list M are part of it.

```
from pyomo.environ import*
model = ConcreteModel
N=[1,2,3] 
U=['A','B','C','D']
model.X = Var(N,U,within=NonNegativeReals)
model.X.pprint()
```

Retrieved from

```
X : Size=12, Index=X_index
Key      : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
(1, 'A') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(1, 'B') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(1, 'C') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(1, 'D') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(2, 'A') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(2, 'B') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(2, 'C') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(2, 'D') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(3, 'A') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(3, 'B') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(3, 'C') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(3, 'D') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
```

This is easy and I know how to do it. But now I want that for each element N[i] the indexing set U is different as well as of different sizes. I have tried to use a list of lists but I don't get what I want.

```
from pyomo.environ import*
model = ConcreteModel
N=[1,2,3] 
U=U=[['A','B','C','D'],['B','C','E','G'],['A','C','D']]
model.X = Var(N,U,within=NonNegativeReals)
model.X.pprint()
```

The result is:

```
The value=['A', 'C', 'D'] has dimension 3 and is not valid for Set OrderedScalarSet which has dimen=4
```

And I want to get

```
X : Size=12, Index=X_index
Key      : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
(1, 'A') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(1, 'B') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(1, 'C') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(1, 'D') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(2, 'B') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(2, 'C') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(2, 'E') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(2, 'G') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(3, 'A') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(3, 'C') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
(3, 'D') :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
```

How can I get it?

Thank you very much and best regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyomo dealing with an indexed index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74465104/pyomo-dealing-with-an-indexed-index)

Comment: Take a look at the example I referenced and the example that is linked within that reference.  They both show how to do this with examples.  Comment back here or on one of those (and reference me) if there is something unclear, or upvote them if they are helpful so they're easier to find with this type of question.

Comment: Thanks for the link @AirSquid. Everything works perfectly now. In case you are interested, the solution proposed by Alon Alush  is also correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom index set that includes the desired combinations of indices from the two lists:

```
from pyomo.environ import *

model = ConcreteModel()

N = [1, 2, 3]
U = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'C', 'E', 'G'], ['A', 'C', 'D']]

# Create a custom index set
index_set = [(n, u) for i, n in enumerate(N) for u in U[i]]

# Create the variable with the custom index set
model.X = Var(index_set, within=NonNegativeReals)
model.X.pprint()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Alon Alush. Everything works as I want it to. If you are interested AirSquid's answer is also correct.